# TypeError('not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object',)

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am using aiohttp get request to download some content from another web api
but i am receiving:

```
exception = TypeError('not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object',)
```

Following is the data which i am trying to sent.

```
data = "symbols=LGND-US&exprs=CS_EVENT_TYPE_CD_R(%27%27,%27now%27,%271D%27)"
```

How to resolve it?

I tried it in 2 ways:

```
r = yield from aiohttp.get(url, params=data) # and
r = yield from aiohttp.post(url, data=data)
```

At the same time i am able to fetch data using:

```
r = requests.get(url, params=data) # and
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

But i need async implementation.

And also suggest me some way if i can use `import requests` library instead of `import aiohttp` to make async http request, because in many cases aiohttp post & get request are not working but the same are working for requests.get & post requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/stable/client.html) use bytes (i.e. the 'b' prefix) for the `data` argument.

```
r = await aiohttp.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data=b'data')
```

Also, the `params` argument should be a dict or a list of tuples.

Comment: i tried with above solution but now i am receiving  Error getting inputs
405

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? You mean HTTP error 405 (method not allowed)? You're probably doing POST and the page only allows GET or vice versa. For a GET you need to use the params argument instead of data, but it needs to be a dict or list as I noted above.

Comment: @miles82 the requirement was relaxed in [aiohttp PR #587](https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/pull/587)